# Layout Design -android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make design like below image for showing popup window.

[image]

I've tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00154271" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#154271"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It&apos;s a PopupWindow" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dismiss" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_facebook" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think is not perfect for all devices because the close image using margin properties. it will differ for all devices. How to make above design for all devices.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00154271" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#154271"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It&apos;s a PopupWindow" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dismiss" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @user3274323,Glad to help you now approve and upvote so it may be also help to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have edited your ..layout..It will work fine now

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00154271" >
  <FrameLayout         android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="10"
               android:background="#154271"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It&apos;s a PopupWindow" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dismiss" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set different Values for multiple devices. For this, You have to create multiple values folders inside the res in Your project. For every folder, You can make dimens.xml. For example, a 7" tablet, create a folder:

```
     res/values-sw600dp
```

inside this folder, specify the dimens:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
    <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_props">20dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

Then, You can refer Your layout_width like this:

```
  <TextView
     android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
     android:text="hello" />
```

or:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_props"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

All values have to be named equal inside the different folders/dimens.xml, but there You can set different dimensions. For example, If You want to set other dimensions for a 10" tablet, create a folder:

```
        res/values-sw720dp
```

and specify the same dimensions with different values:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
    <dimen name="textview_height">35dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_width">180dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_size">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_props">30dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

I recommend You to read the multiple screen support from here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

**No need to change your layout. Just adjust that properties. Try this**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00154271" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#154271"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It&apos;s a PopupWindow" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dismiss" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"//your image width/2
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"//your image width/2
        android:src="@drawable/icon_facebook" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this to your imageview with cross:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_facebook" />
```

I fixed the image's width and height and put margin about half of the width. This is how I did it in my project. choose appropriate dp values.